# Sort internal array timestamps

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp, highcharts

I have an array with multiple elements that looks like this:

```
  {
"name": "DR",
"data": [
  [
    "1508112000000",
    4
  ],
  [
    "1534204800000",
    1
  ]
],
"type": "areaspline"
},
{
    "name": "SIT",
    "data": [
      [
        "1508112000000",
        4
      ],
      [
        "1534204800000",
        1
      ],
      [
        "1506384000000",
        3
      ],
      [
        "1534204800000",
        1
      ],
      [
        "1531094400000",
        1
      ],
      [
        "1528502400000",
        1
      ]
    ],
    "type": "areaspline"
  },
```

This is the exact format I use to send data into high charts, however, the problem is that the chart breaks if the timestamps inside each environment (DR, SIT) are not in order.

How can I sort the 'data' inside each environment by timestamp?

This JSON is generated in PHP and sent through to JavaScript. So I would like to know how to sort the data inside either PHP or JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? Share your code

Comment: [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) has been known to work for this task. Have you tried it?

Comment: it would definitely be useful to see your current attempt, so that we can help hone in on the specific part of the implementation you are struggling with.

Comment: Why sort it at the client? You're generating this in php but you can't sort it there? [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: @Yehudah - first problem is that `"1531094400000"` is a String, Highcharts require Number (`1531094400000`). Then use mentioned `Array.sort()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually rather trivial, once you know about the `usort` function.  It allows you to define your own sorting function, so you can sort based on any factor of whatever the 2 objects it is passed.

Note that from your example json I had to add a set of square brackets around the whole thing to get PHP to parse it with `json_decode` .

```
<?php

// note I had to add square brackets to your
// demo json ....

$json='[{
"name": "DR",
"data": [
  [
    "1508112000000",
    4
  ],
  [
    "1534204800000",
    1
  ]
],
"type": "areaspline"
},
{
    "name": "SIT",
    "data": [
      [
        "1508112000000",
        4
      ],
      [
        "1534204800000",
        1
      ],
      [
        "1506384000000",
        3
      ],
      [
        "1534204800000",
        1
      ],
      [
        "1531094400000",
        1
      ],
      [
        "1528502400000",
        1
      ]
    ],
    "type": "areaspline"
  }]';

$json_obj_arr=json_decode($json,true);

print_r($json_obj_arr);
print("\n\n");

// a function to handle the sorting itself
// usort will pass it an array(timestamp,datavalue) for both
// $a and $b so we compare the [0] element of each
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}


// loop through the array, first is indexed
for($i=0;$i<count($json_obj_arr);$i++){
    // then each one of those contains an
    // associtive array with an element named ['data'] -
    // this is an indexed array that you want sorted
    // on the [0] element

    usort($json_obj_arr[$i]['data'],"cmp");
}

print_r($json_obj_arr);
print("\n\n");
?>
```